# button onclick event not firing while onclientClick returns true in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have simple code in asp.net after adding onClient click onClick stop responding while oclient click returning true please can any one suggest......

```
 function loginEmpty() {
                debugger
                var flag = true;
                var name = document.getElementById("username").value;
                var pass = document.getElementById("userpassword").value;


            if (name =='' || pass =='') {

               document.getElementById('username').style.border = "solid 1px red";
               document.getElementById('userpassword').style.border = "solid 1px red";

               document.getElementById('loginMsg').style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById('errorMsg').style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = "Required field can not leave blank.";
               flag= false;

            }
            else {

                flag = true;
                document.getElementById('username').style.border = "solid 1px green";
                document.getElementById('userpassword').style.border = "solid 1px green";
                document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = "   . ";

            }
            return flag;

        }
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML

Comment: Please show aspx code

Comment: Check what you are returning from the OnClientClick function - I believe returning false will prevent postback from occurring.

Comment: Would it not be a load easier to use a RequiredFieldValidator and a ValidationSummary?? All this work is done for you then!

Answer (score 0):

For example below is your button :

Add `return` before you call JavaScript method as mentioned in below sample:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="My Button" ID="myButton" OnClientClick="return loginEmpty();" OnClick="myButton_OnClick" />
```